# Loopback Access Token To Flask

Tags: python, flask, loopbackjs

I have setup a loopback API, and I plan to use the login as such flask would make requests to loopback and loopback returns an `accessToken`

For example login to dashboard:

```
# Login route
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    status = ""
    url_login = 'http://localhost:3000/api/Users/login'

    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.form['username']
            password =  request.form['password']


            payload_login = {
            "username": str(username),
            "password":str(password)
            }
            print(payload_login)


            r = requests.post(url_login, data=payload_login).text
            access_token = json.loads(r)

            # access_token = r['id']
            # access_token = json.loads(access_token)
            print("Access Token: " + str(access_token['id']))

            return redirect('/') #CHANGE TO 404 PAGE


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return redirect('/') #CHANGE TO 404 PAGE

    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def logged_in_dashboard():


    return render_template('index.html')
```

How do I set it up so that login to dashboard requires accessToken from loopback? In the past I've used `app.config['ACCESS_KEY'] ='key'` and have set that if it contains a token it would allow the user to login.

But I'm not sure if this is a good practice. Anything you would like to recommend that could handle lots of user logins?

Comment: You can try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510290/how-do-you-implement-token-authentication-in-flask

Comment: I'd suggest not to do a request within a request as the first request will stall as long as a response was received from the second/nested request (even though you're requesting from `localhost`).

Answer (score 3):

Don't create requests to the API from within the API. To share functionality between endpoints, use functions. You need at least two functions here:

1. a function returns a token for valid credentials
2. a function that requires the token being present in the session or in the request `Authorization` header, for example

Check the approach that chans linked to for more implementation details: [How do you implement token authentication in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510290/how-do-you-implement-token-authentication-in-flask)

Or the official tutorial for how to implement sessions: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions

Which has something like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # this if is the login requirement
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % escape(session['username'])
    return 'You are not logged in'

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Add logic for validating username and password here.
        # If credentials are ok, set username to session.
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return '''
        <form method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''
```